# Can garage door track read hangers be at an angle?

Tags: hanging, garage-door

I'm trying to install a garage door where I don't have ceiling joists, just a big beam and two horizontal members between the wall and the beam. I can't put the angle bracket on the horizontal member or it causes the track to not be square (unless I do something terrible like flatten the bracket)

I want to mount the track hanger on the beam, but then it will be at an angle. The bracket would follow the path of the tape measure in the photo. If I do that, I can fashion a standard triangle hanger with angle bracket. It would meet the garage door track at an angle though.

(Note: the vertical angle bracket on the photo is *not* staying; I'm not asking if that's safe because it obviously isn't.)

[image: photo of garage door hanger track]

I couldn't find any guidance online about this. Note that this is a spring extension door, so the spring would hook onto the bracket.

Is it safe to mount the angle bracket hanger at an angle?

Comment: Am I reading this right? You have the header and perpendicular beams, where the header and one of these beams is shown in the photo. The perpendicular beam spacing and locations do not allow the tracks to be correct for the garage door opening. The shown track is currently mounted on a beam, but you need a detail that anchors to the header instead so that you can get the spacing and location correct.

Comment: The shown bracket has a stabilizing "kicker" running diagonally. If your hanger is slanted, then the hanger below its connection with the kicker will work in bending to fight gravity load in addition to dynamic load. You would want the kicker tying into the hanger much closer to the hanger/rail connection to minimize this bending. The kicker loses its effectiveness if it runs parallel to the hanger, so you wouldn't be able to anchor it to the header also.

Comment: You have the layout correct, but the track is not connected. I'm hesitant to use it because will be nothing stopping the spring from twisting/bending it. I want to do a proper hanger [like this](https://www.garagedoorstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/anglekit_guide.jpg) but there is no joist running parallel to the door. I just have the beam that's parallel to the door and two perpendicular members between the beam and the header. I want to hang it from the beam, but then the hanger will be at an angle (like the tape measure in the photo).

Answer (score 0):

For the connection shown, add a vertically oriented chunk of blocking to the side of your beam. The block's thickness must be chosen so that the hanger hangs plumb. The angle will sit nicely on the corner of the block, so the leg pointing toward the beam isn't a problem.

Amend your question with another image if the same pattern doesn't work on the other track.

Comment: Blocking is actually what I did on the other side and it works out fine. On this side, the spacing is is that of I block, it moves the track to far inwards; doing similar on the other side of the beam pushed the track too far out. I was think of hanging it directly under, but then the face of the bracket with the spring attached won't be attached to anything (which is the problem with the "flattened" bracket in the photo)

Comment: @Scribblemacher, by "moves the track too far inwards," do you mean that the leg of the angle pointing toward the beam is interfering with the correct offset? That can be remedied by notching the angle. How deep of a notch would it take? What is that angle's leg length? There's also a cute pattern where you can toe the angle attached to the beam inward, but make it too short to reach the rail. Then lap another piece of angle back-to-back with the toe pointed the other direction, where this correctly oriented angle supports the track.